# how to read or display epub file from aws s3 bucket without downloading?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, epub

I have a set content type like this but it isn't work for me in epub case

```
 const params = {
      Bucket: AWS_BUCKET,
      Key: isEpub ? `common/files/epubs/${contenttype}` : `common/files/docs/${contenttype}`,
      Body: fileStream,
      ContentEncoding: 'base64',
      ContentDisposition: 'inline',
      ContentType: file.type,
      ACL: 'public-read'
    }
```

Comment: check contentype & mime type might could help

Comment: contenttype = application/epub+zip